# Store a day of week (mon, tue, wed, ...) in rails db and compare with the day of today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am developing a rails 3.1 app where I need to store opening hours for stores. I want to store opening time, closing time and the day of the week. My first idea is to store a day number where 1 is monday and 7 sunday but is there a better approach which is more suitable when I want to internationalize my application?
If i store the day number, how can I compare it with the day of week today to check if the store is open or not?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track. To figure out the current day of the week:

```
Date.today.wday
```

Although that considers Sunday 0 and Saturday 6.

Comment: Thanks, I want to make sure that the numbering doesn't change when I switch locale but this seems to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

A number value should be fine. Use the numbers used by the Ruby Time class to keep things simple: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000369

Sunday will be 0, Monday 1, etc...

Comment: Thanks! I will number the days as you suggested.